# A sub-optimal solution that does not guarantee that all MSTs are found in a reasonable time

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx, minimum-spanning-tree

The calculation of all MSTs of a graph is infeasible in practice. This is because the number of all MSTs has an upper bound of n power (n-2), where n is the number of nodes in the graph.

Therefore finding all MSTs of a graph is known to be an NP-hard problem (its computational complexity is exponential).

How can I find a sub-optimal solution (that is a solution that does not guarantee that all MSTs are found) in a reasonable time?

Comment: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/pubs/Epp-TR-95-50.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by sub-optimal?  One that finds just some of the MSTs?  90% of them?  50% of them?  One of them?

Comment: Let's say 90%  of them.